# I have 2 versions of Adobe Reader

Tags: uninstall, adobe-reader, adobe-acrobat

I once installed Reader from the Adobe website. It was full of bugs and didn't come with text in the menu so I decided to uninstall it and install a different version. I tried:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove acroread
sudo apt-get remove acroread
sudo apt-get purge acroread
```

In the end the program still stayed on my computer and managed to launch. Then I installed nearly the same version of Reader from the Software Center. The one from the Software Center worked perfectly but I still have the buggy version. How do I remove it? I have tried searching for it in the Software Center but didn't find it there. Thankfully PDF documents open with the new version but when I search the program in the launcher, I see 2 exact icons of Reader.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reinstall the version of the old reader via sudo command in the terminal or thru the browser if that's how you got it. Once you install it you need should go thru the software centre and uninstall it from there and if that doesn't work then try sudo .... You could also just change the name of the application I'm assuming by its .jason or json file ?? I know that works via windows and or you could find the package in your system folder and try to do it from there however I would use the first two and I strongly thing the last shouldn't be used becuase it may cause instability on the system if you remove bits an peice instead of chunks ... Have you checked to make sure the package name is correct if you have two of the same application I wouldn't think they could run at the same time using the same package name. Also just thought of it : have you tried removing both thru the software centre ??? Try removing the new and then the old or via versa ..

A wild guess also check your system for viruses some are cross platform and adobe reader would be a good way to sneak in a virus.....  And yes I know you said that you had downloaded it from there website but maybe it was a very good phishing version??? It's happened to me before with avg

Comment: seems like you didnt understand, these programs work like 2 completely seporate programs. the glitchy version cannot be found in the software center. and how could a virus get into my computer if i downloaded it from the official website. Espetially in a unix like operating system

Comment: in fact, after trying what you listed, now neither of the versions work

Comment: When did they stop working after what set of directions? I know from experenve that Ubuntu 12.04 and 13 you can do something really minor and it affects the who system ....

Comment: If you go in to the application info are the readers both a different version ?

Comment: i cant go to application info cuz neither apps work. i need to know where the program folder is located to remove it manually. then reinstall cuz i try to install the soft-cent version and it installs but in the end it says that i dont have it installed. its messed up

Comment: Try uninstalling with synaptic package manager . I'm not sure we're the program folder is ill let you know when I figure it out

Comment: yes that helped, i used synaptic package manager to remove the program, rebooted my computer, installed reader using softcenter, rebooted again, and now i still get 2 exact icons in gnome dash menu, however both of them lead to the same program (the one that works). now everything is good accept for the fact that there are 2 icons in the dash menu but thats not too big of a deal
thanks

Comment: Ok yay :)glad to have helped. Sorry about messing it up earlier